# how to set the same height as the parent element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, katex

I would like to know to align the text in a `p` element to be vertically centered.

Here is my code:

```css
p.task{font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: 700;  display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
span.label {float: left; width: 60px; color: red}
span.text {float: left; width: calc(100% - 60px);}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p class="task">
  <span class="label">2</span>
  <span class="text">Vypočtěte jednu třetinu z \( 3^{3k+3} \) , kde \( k \space \epsilon \space Z \).</span>
</p>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" 
    onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
```

Comment: You can use <p align="center">...</p> to align your text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `vertical-center` class to the **p**.

```
.vertical-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

or can add the above 2 style-rules within the **task** class.

```
.task {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 700;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Flex is great. But you need to check if all the browsers you want to support can handle it. Check out https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox